plot bars from highest to lowest in each facet
I'm trying to order the bars id from highest to lowest within each facet facet_var.
The script below worked fine for most of the facets except NGRRR.V. Not sure what went wrong and how can I fix it?
Result

What I have tried?
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
dat <- as.data.table(df)

dat[, ord := sprintf("%02i", frank(dat, facet_var, -value, ties.method = "first"))] 

ggplot(dat, aes(x = ord, y = value, fill = id)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ facet_var, scales = "free", drop = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = dat[, setNames(as.character(id), ord)]) +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.text = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 8))

Data
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = structure(c(12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 
7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 
9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 
8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 
7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 
9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 
8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 
7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 
9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L), levels = c("973", 
"1264", "1472", "1993", "2097", "2221", "2987", "3655", "4009", 
"5890", "16000", "16471"), class = "factor"), Q = c(6.59, 6.67, 
1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 
6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 
6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 
6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 
3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 
4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 
3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 
5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 
3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 
15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 
9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 6.67, 
1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 6.59, 
6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 6.3, 2.96, 
6.59, 6.67, 1.74, 9.92, 15.55, 3.76, 5.72, 3.83, 4.95, 3.58, 
6.3, 2.96), value = c(4.58, 4.78, 1.18, 8.59, 11.89, 3.03, 4.19, 
2.8, 3.65, 2.54, 4.57, 2.19, 0.1, 0.1, 0.02, 0.08, 0.18, 0.03, 
0.08, 0.06, 0.07, 0.05, 0.09, 0.04, 0.78, 0.81, 0.17, 0.64, 1.5, 
0.29, 0.69, 0.47, 0.61, 0.43, 0.77, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.08, 0.3, 
0.7, 0.13, 0.33, 0.22, 0.29, 0.21, 0.37, 0.17, 0.07, 0.07, 0.01, 
0.05, 0.12, 0.02, 0.06, 0.04, 0.05, 0.04, 0.06, 0.03, 0.23, 0.24, 
0.05, 0.2, 0.45, 0.09, 0.21, 0.14, 0.18, 0.13, 0.23, 0.11, 0.34, 
0.35, 0.06, 0.25, 0.6, 0.11, 0.29, 0.2, 0.26, 0.19, 0.33, 0.15, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.06, 0.25, 0.6, 0.11, 0.29, 0.2, 0.26, 0.19, 0.33, 
0.15, 0.22, 0.22, 0.04, 0.16, 0.38, 0.07, 0.19, 0.13, 0.17, 0.12, 
0.21, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.03, 0.11, 0.26, 0.05, 0.12, 0.08, 0.11, 
0.08, 0.14, 0.06, 0.34, 0.34, 0.07, 0.25, 0.6, 0.12, 0.28, 0.19, 
0.24, 0.18, 0.32, 0.14, 2.7, 2.88, 0.76, 7.18, 8.41, 2.38, 2.63, 
1.71, 2.26, 1.53, 2.77, 1.38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), facet_var = c("ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", 
"ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", "ALLZN", 
"IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", 
"IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", "IRNGT", "KARAM", "KARAM", 
"KARAM", "KARAM", "KARAM", "KARAM", "KARAM", "KARAM", "KARAM", 
"KARAM", "KARAM", "KARAM", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", 
"KRM.G", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", "KRM.G", 
"KRM.G", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", 
"KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "KRWRW", "MNGTR", 
"MNGTR", "MNGTR", "MNGTR", "MNGTR", "MNGTR", "MNGTR", "MNGTR", 
"MNGTR", "MNGTR", "MNGTR", "MNGTR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR", 
"NGRRR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR", 
"NGRRR", "NGRRR", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", 
"NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", 
"NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.M", "NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", 
"NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", 
"NGRRR.V", "NGRRR.V", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", 
"RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", "RAUPR", 
"TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", 
"TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TTK.W", "TUKTK", "TUKTK", 
"TUKTK", "TUKTK", "TUKTK", "TUKTK", "TUKTK", "TUKTK", "TUKTK", 
"TUKTK", "TUKTK", "TUKTK", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", 
"TUTKR", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", "TUTKR", 
"TUTKR")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -156L))


See tidytext::reorder_within(): https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/

The issue is that you pad your "ranks" with only one zero instead of two. Hence, you can fix your issue by padding with two zeros, i.e.
dat[, ord := sprintf("%03i", frank(dat, facet_var, -value, ties.method = "first"))] 

Or instead of padding with zeros convert the ranks to a factor (so that your approach to add the ids as labels still works):
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dat <- as.data.table(df)

dat[, ord := factor(frank(dat, facet_var, -value, ties.method = "first"))]

ggplot(dat, aes(x = ord, y = value, fill = id)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~facet_var, scales = "free", drop = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = dat[, setNames(as.character(id), ord)]) +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.text = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 8)
  )



Many thanks Stefan. I highly appreciate your time and help.
